# How to move mail to junk folder - Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I have some problem with move incoming email to junk folder. I'm writing Thunderbird extension and I use function `CopyMessage()` from `nsIMsgMessageService` to move incoming mail to junk folder.
I have problem with use this function. In documentation of this function, is writing "Pass in the URI for the message you want to have copied. aCopyListener already knows about the destination folder." Variable aCopyListener is a interface from `nsIStreamListener` and i don't see any properties who would have information about the destination incoming mail. How to properly use this function and copy message to junky folder?

Link for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIMsgMessageService#CopyMessage()

```
function listMessages(aFolder) {  
Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/iteratorUtils.jsm");
let database = aFolder.msgDatabase; 
for each (let msgHdr in fixIterator(database.EnumerateMessages(),
Components.interfaces.nsIMsgDBHdr)) {
let title = msgHdr.mime2DecodedSubject;
let messenger = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIMessenger);
let listener = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/sync-stream-listener;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISyncStreamListener);
let uri = msgHdr.folder.getUriForMsg(msgHdr);
var messageService = messenger.messageServiceFromURI(uri); 
messenger.messageServiceFromURI(uri).streamMessage(uri, listener, null, null, false, "");
let folder = msgHdr.folder;
let messageBody = folder.getMsgTextFromStream(listener.inputStream,
                   msgHdr.Charset,
                   65536,
                   32768,
                   false,
                   true,
                   { }); 
var incomingMail = folder.server.rootFolder.getChildNamed("Odebrane");
var junkyMail = folder.server.rootFolder.getChildNamed("Niechciane");
messageService.CopyMessage(incomingMail.URI, listener, true, null, null, new Object);
  } 
  aFolder.msgDatabase = null;
  database.forceFolderDBClosed(aFolder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to copy the currently selected message to another folder:

```
Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/mailServices.js");

var msgs = Cc["@mozilla.org/array;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIMutableArray);
msgs.appendElement(gFolderDisplay.selectedMessage, false);

var isMove = false;
var copyService = MailServices.copy; // nsIMsgCopyService
let destFolder = gFolderDisplay.displayedFolder.rootFolder;
copyService.CopyMessages(gFolderDisplay, msgs, destFolder, isMove, CopyListener, null, false);
```